# Differential Update With SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication, firebird, dts, database

I have several huge (2GB each) database in Firebird format. Every few weeks, this data has to be synchronized with an MS SQL Server. Currently this is a long winded process which just truncates the destination tables then copies each row with Database Workbench (a multi DB DBMS). Is there any clever way to do a partial or differential update which would speed up the process or involve less pumping of data between servers?

Comment: The best way to do this optimizing data transfer is using a journaling system in your database. Would you like to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try making a hash (MD5 or similar) of each record? If you also store/calculate on the fly an MD5 hash of your loaded data then you can quickly determine using primary keys of a table and the MD5 hash if anything has changed, or indeed if a record doesnt exist.

This of course would need to be done on a table by table basis.

We have used a similar method using SQL OLTP data as a source into a DWH, works very nicely!